# dynamically Changing the value of Progress Bar with the changing value of an integer

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have a progress bar.
I have an increasing int. which i name questionindex
I want the progress bar to move just as the integer increases. i.e i want the value of the progressbar to increase as the value of my incremented int increases.
I wrote :

```
ProgressBar.value= questionindex;
```

questionindex is my Int
An exemption was raised saying I can't convert Int to double

Then I used:

```
ProgressBar.value = questionindex.Tostring();
```

It said I can't convert string to double lacking an e. Property.
Then I create a hidden textblock. I set the text property  to my Int.

```
textBlock.Text= questionindex;
```

Then equated this to progress bar

```
ProgressBar.value= textBlock.Text
```

none of these bits worked.

Comment: Are you sure it is the error you're getting? The compiler should be able to implicitly convert an `int` to `double`. In any case, you can use `Convert.ToDouble(questionindex);` to convert the int to double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on mine.

```
int i = 0
while (i < 100)
{
    progressBar.Value = i;
    i++;
}
```

the value takes an `int`.

If you are creating the progress bar, then you need to it the step and the maximum value before using it.

Also note you to create one use

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
```

Thanks for the edit

Comment: The `OP` is writing a WP8 app, there's no use in importing the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

A friend just helped. i used this little code and it worked.

```
ProgressBar.value= Double.Parse(questionindex.ToString());
```

the Progress Bar increased and moved as the integer increased. the minimum and maximum were set automatically by visual studio.